# Angular Animation for ng-repeat not working

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I would like to do a simple fade in animation for the items that my `ng-repeat` generates, I followed all the instructions on the [ngAnimate site](http://www.nganimate.org/) but still no dice.

Here is my module

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
```

Here is the `ng-repeat` in my markup

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="mark in marks" ng-animate="'animate' ">
  <div class="col-md-12 well well-sm" >
    <div data-ng-include="'./Partials/mark.html'" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is some CSS for the animation

```
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And here are the scripts I'm including

```
<!-- JS -->

<!-- Vendor Libs -->
<script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- UI Libs -->
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- App libs -->
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./Controllers/MarksController.js"></script>
<script src="./Controllers/ViewMarkController.js"></script>
<script src="./Services/marksService.js"></script>
```

*) All the required CSS files are also linked in my header.

*) Link to Project: https://www.mediafire.com/?6h1qwcrblqczjpr

Comment: can you perhaps create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Cannot right now, but will try to do so later. Is there not enough info in the post?

Comment: It makes it easier for everyone if there is working/non-working example. You will find sometimes when you strip out your code to the bear minimum you find the problem before you need to ask the question.

Comment: I see. How do I proceed on JS fiddle if, for instance my route config is referring to a Template URL that is pointing to a separate html file? Since one can only insert links to scripts and css.

Comment: You don't have to copy your entire entire project/code base. Just create a single controller/directive and add your css. Essentially only add the code that is relevant to your issue. In your case its the animation that's not working so only add that relevant code.

Comment: You can fork one of my jsfiddles and modify as you need https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/rsqs2r1x/1/

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. I added the same basic code needed for the animation on your JSFiddle project that I forked, but it's still not working :https://jsfiddle.net/b5x65dw5/1/

Comment: Updated my post with a link to full project (small, not a lot of code)

Comment: _"ngAnimate site"_ is about Angular 1.1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `ng-animate="'animate'"` directive.

All you need to do is add a class to the intended item, and add the relevant `angualrjs` animate classes.

Please see the code below:

```
.animate-repeat {    
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    transition: 1s linear all;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
    max-height:40px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="RestaurantsController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search_cat.name">
    <br>
    <b>Category:</b>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in cuisines">
        <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="cat.checked" /> {{cat.name}}</b>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div ng-repeat="w in filtered=(restaurants | filter:filterByCategory) " class="animate-repeat">
        {{w.name}}
    </div>
    <hr /> Number of results: {{filtered.length}}
</div>
```

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/b5x65dw5/2/)

From the [source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)

> **Animations**
>
> AngularJS provides animation hooks for common directives such as ngRepeat, ngSwitch, and ngView, as well as custom directives via the $animate service. These animation hooks are set in place to trigger animations during the life cycle of various directives and when triggered, will attempt to perform a CSS Transition, CSS Keyframe Animation or a JavaScript callback Animation (depending on if an animation is placed on the given directive). Animations can be placed using vanilla CSS by following the naming conventions set in place by AngularJS or with JavaScript code when it's defined as a factory.
>
> Animations are not available unless you include the ngAnimate module as a dependency within your application.